# Python, using IN operator keeps returning false

Tags: python, substring

I'm trying to find a substring within a dataframe object. I'm turning the dataframe object into a string before i do this.

Even though i know for sure that the substring exists in the dataframe object, the "in" operator keeps returning false.

I've spent hours trying to figure out how else i can do this. I've also tried using

```
df1.str.contains
```

but it errors out.

Can someone please let me know what i'm doing wrong? I'm willing to try different approaches if necessary.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
changesfull = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\changes\changes.xlsx'
locations = pd.read_excel(changesfull)

for change in changes:
   y = y+1
   z = z+1
   g = g+1

   df1 = locations.iloc[y:z,2:3]
   newframe = "product" in str(df1)
   print(newframe)
```

When i print out str(df1), I get an output of dataframe object:

"1  Effective July 15, 2018 - the following produc..."

Could it be that its unable to find the word product because it doesn't acutally print the full thing? eg. it should be " - the following product is available"

Comment: try printing `str(df1)` to see what you get

Comment: @SuperStew I did. And i've included the output in the question now at the bottom.

Comment: "Could it be that its unable to find the word product because it doesn't acutally print the full thing?" Yes that is likely the case.

Comment: How would I fix that though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this actually helps anyone in the future:

The issue was with my my iloc i was using.

I changed that portion to the following and it worked:

```
df1 = locations.iloc[y,2]
```